# Magento 1.9.2.2 on php 7 version discount is not working

Tags: php, magento-1.9

we are working on a ecommerce site buit on magento 1.9.2.2 recently we upgraded php version form 5 to 7, after upgrading the discount calculation through out the site is not working.

For example if my subtotal is 100 and discount is 10 still the grandtotal returns as 100 which should actually be 90.

Can anyone please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: This could be anything :-) Could you post some code examples where you calculate the discount? (You can edit your question). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its when i add discount coupon to the magento website in shopping cart section where the subtotal and grand total is displayed discount is not getting applied on grand total, the calculation is done at magento level there is no specific code we are using to calculate

Comment: I'm almost certain thing has nothing to do with the PHP version (basic maths doesn't work differently in 5 and 7). If you look up previous posts about Magento inconsisently and inaccurately calculating totals/subtotals you'll find thousands of posts... It's more of a coincidence you didn't spot the problem on PHP 5 than anything else :)

Comment: It appears that Magento 1.9.2. is not compatible with PHP 7.x yet. Have you tried something like https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7 ?

Comment: Thank you so much this worked for me.

Comment: I've added the comment as answer. If you could accept it for future reference. :) Glad that it works now!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Magento 1.9.2.x is not compatible with PHP 7.x (yet).

A library could work help overcome compatibility issues:
https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7